# SQL Server 2012 & Polybase - 'Hadoop Connectivity' configuration option missing

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sql-server-2012

As described in the title, I am using SQL Server 2012 Parallel Data Warehouse with Polybase feature to try to access a HDInisght Hadoop cluster.

As a starting point for every connection to Hadoop from SQL Server, I find to execute the command

```
sp_configure  @configname =  'hadoop connectivity',
          @configvalue =  { 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 };
RECONFIGURE;
```

Upon execution, I receive the following error:

> The configuration option 'hadoop connectivity' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.

Please note I have advanced options set to 1 (visible) and can see other advanced options, when running `sp_configure` on its own.
It seems the only [option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631.aspx) I am missing is the hadoop connectivity.

I would be glad if anyone with a similar problem has a solution to either make the option visible or to set the value via a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure Polybase is installed and enabled?

You should have installed it during the [SQL Server installation process](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-XMKxyJG51Kw/VWheZsbgX5I/AAAAAAAAFPA/-HOu5Q7CyRs/s1600/image14.png) and [enable the according services](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-z7RhtYZpZzY/VWheeLgtAGI/AAAAAAAAFPI/SOxeteVKGdc/s1600/image15.png).

Comment: Seems like the service was not installed on the machine, thank you for your answer.